# How to transfer money directly to customers wirecard account

Tags: php, payment

we want to be able via PHP to payout money directly to a customers wirecard-Account.
For this, I checked out the paymentSDK-php from github, but I can not find out how it could be possible.
There a many different Payment-Methods like PayPal, PaysafeCard, etc, but no method like wirecard to wirecard.
https://github.com/wirecard/paymentSDK-php

Does somebody have some Tipps or Hints, if this sdk is the right one
or should we better use another one or create an own one?

Thanks for your answers.
Frank

Answer (score 1):

The paymentSDK published on GitHub is only intended to be used for implementing payments from customers to merchants. Should you require a solution for transactions from one Wirecard account to another, consider contacting the [sales/partner management](https://www.wirecard.com/contact/partner/) directly. They may be able to offer a fitting solution.